# How do I update semantic ui dropdown list with vue?

Tags: vue.js, semantic-ui

I'm trying to update the semantic ui dropdown with new values. Vue is correctly being updated and I'm refreshing the semantic ui dropdown but it still isn't updating. I saw another post which mentioned the use of key, but it still fails.

**Template**

```
<div id=root>
  <label>Type:</label>
  <select id="app_type" class="ui search selection dropdown" v-model="model_type_val">
    <option v-for="model_type in model_types" v-bind:value="model_type.value" v-bind:key="model_type.value">{{model_type.text}}</option>
  </select>
  <p>
    selected: {{model_type_val}}
  </p>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
var model_types2= [
  {value:"",text:"Type"},
  {value:"type1",text:"Type1a"},
  {value:"type2",text:"Type2a"},
  {value:"type3",text:"Type3a"},
  {value:"type4",text:"Type4"}      
];

var vm2= new Vue({
  el:'#root',
  data:{
    model_type_val:"",
    model_types:[
      {value:"",text:"Type"},
      {value:"type1",text:"Type1"},
      {value:"type2",text:"Type2"},
      {value:"type3",text:"Type3"}
    ]
  },
  mounted: function(){
    $('#app_type').dropdown();
    setTimeout(function() {
      this.model_types=model_types2;
      alert(this.model_types[1].text);
      $('#app_type').dropdown('refresh');              
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

I've tried to reproduce the code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tvinci/nh6tao4y/5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `this` problem. When you have a callback inside a Vue method or lifecycle hook in which you use `this`, you need to make sure that `this` points to the correct object (the Vue). You do that with an arrow function, a closure, or `bind`.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.model_types=model_types2;
  $('#app_type').dropdown('refresh');              
}, 1000);
```

Here is your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/aLvyz6ps/).

Note: In the fiddle, I also converted your selector to use a `ref`. Typically you want to start weaning yourself off jQuery when working with Vue.

See [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I like the jquery tip too. I haven't used ref before. I've been using jquery for so long, it's my default when trying to write something quick. I was hoping to escape it when moving to vue; but semantic uses it. :)

Comment: I've altered your jsfiddle to remove the last element and change only the text for one of the entries. Do you know why it doesn't update? https://jsfiddle.net/tvinci/5dkb2r62/

Comment: @user2265754 It's believe it's because of the `key`, `model_type.value`. By using that as a key and replacing the options with a list that has the same `key`, Vue is re-using the original. Seems weird that didn't also happen before. I've changed [updated the code](https://jsfiddle.net/5dkb2r62/1/) though and removed a few lines I don't think are necessary.

Comment: Perfect! This was my original issue which I was unable to reproduce in the first jsfiddle. :) I spent hours trying to figure out what was wrong. This is my first time with Vue and Semantic. I'm trying to switch from getuikit and jquery.